# Can I easily tune the mathdesign fonts?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols

My main text font is Utopia. The `mathdesign` package contains a set of mathematical symbols that match this font pretty nicely. I noticed two small things that I don't like, especially in comparison with other math fonts.

With my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\setmainfont{Utopia}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    a \propto \frac{\partial B}{\partial C}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

the symbol for proportionality is extremely large. Furthermore the distance between the partial sign and the variable is also much larger than for example in the standard font.

[image]

Here it looks in my opinion much better:

[image]

Can I somehow tune these two aspects of mathdesign in combination with the Utopia font?

Comment: I also recommend the [`fourier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fourier) package which uses Utopia for text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get the proportional sign better,  I used `\hstretch` from the `scalerel` package, squeezing it to 70% of its original width.  (I used egreg's fix for the partial-derivative spacing, but with even more space removal)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{scalerel}
%% Most efficient way
\edef\partial{\mathchar\number\partial\noexpand\!\noexpand\!}
\let\svpropto\propto
\renewcommand\propto{\mathrel{\hstretch{.7}{\svpropto}}}

%% Different way
% \let\oldpartial\partial
% \renewcommand{\partial}{\oldpartial\!}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a \propto \frac{\partial B}{\partial C}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The `\propto` symbol I get is not so wide as in your picture.

Here's how to reduce the excessive spacing after `\partial`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}

%% Most efficient way
\edef\partial{\mathchar\number\partial\noexpand\!}

%% Different way
% \let\oldpartial\partial
% \renewcommand{\partial}{\oldpartial\!}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a \propto \frac{\partial B}{\partial C}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]